How to pass a value from one test to another one?
I am part of a developers team maintaining multiple B2B .NET APIs under regulations.
For each release, we deploy the release branch to our dev environment then we do a series of queries manually in swagger:

create a customer
Create a cart
Add a subscription in the cart
Checkout the cart
Confirm the bought subscription is registered to the customer
Suspending the subscription
Reactivating the subscription
Etc.

We are already doing our unit tests in nunit. Some API partner may take like 5 minutes to response for a POST, like creating a customer.
We are considering to use nunit to automate this process and break knowingly rules that tests should be independent and should be run on any order.
How could we technically pass the result of a test to another test?
Examples:

When the customer is created, the next test should know the created CustomerId.
When a subscription is created, the next test should know the SubscriptionId.
Etc.

Thank you!

You need shared memory, static or dynamic - DB, Memory mapped file, Redis DB, File on disk, etc

Put all things you want to test in one test? You want to make them dependent so they are logiacally becoming a single test.

@T.S. Is your suggestion is to persist the data generated by the current test required for the next test through whatever means, like a "local storage" ?

Yes. If your tests are completely separate processes...

Why do you want to do that in the first place?

Also,it sounds like you're actually making calls to those other APIs in your automated tests. Don't, because you'll end up with slow and brittle tests that way. Look up how to use test doubles to provide fake implementations that you can control for testing.

For NUnit you can use the SetUpFixture which is:

the attribute that marks a class that contains the one-time setup or teardown methods for all the test fixtures in a given namespace including nested namespaces below, within an assembly.

So you just place class marked with the attribute into the root of the test project (and root namespace) and perform the needed actions as a one time setup creating the "shared" data (obviously you can have multiple such fixtures when different sets of data are needed for some subsets of tests):
[SetUpFixture]
public class RootSetup
{
    // Use it in all tests
    // also consider making User an immutable type
    public static readonly User UserForAllTests; 
    
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void RunBeforeAnyTests()
    {
        User = ... // get user
    }
}

Also you can use the OneTimeSetUp on per test class basis which can be combined with Order:
public class MySetOfScenarios
{
    private int I;
    private int J;

    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void BaseSetUp()
    {
        J = 7;
    }
    
    [Test, Order(1)]
    public void TestA()
    {
        I = 42;
        TestContext.Out.WriteLine(J); // Outputs 7
        J = 1;
    }

    [Test, Order(2)]
    public void TestB()
    {
        TestContext.Out.WriteLine(I); // Outputs 42
        TestContext.Out.WriteLine(J); // Outputs 1
    }
}

Note that the Order approach in general is discouraged and there are some caveats. For example NUnit does not enforce (as far as I can see) "previous" test to be run if you run only one of the "following" i.e. the #2 test will fail if it would be run independently (if it relies on the data from #1).

Thank you for the suggestion, but after that, we need another for the CartId, for the SubscriptionId, etc. ? It will end up like @Ralf proposed in the comment: one big test?

@TomSawyer TBH do not fully understand your question. The provided code does not have any tests, it has a setup for tests. I.e. you setup the data which will be used by all of the tests (i.e. the shared one). Without seeing the code and knowing actual details it is hard to tell what exactly and how exactly it can be shared.

@TomSawyer see also another/extended option

Technically, you won't pass results of one test directly to another.  You use common declared functions that handle your assertions and return a class with the test results.  That way, you don't have to keep writing the same code in each test.  But you will persist retrieved results, using a service implementation of your choice.  You'd need some way to clean up persistence after all tests are done.
Something like (I use Xunit, so translate as you need):
_ISomePersistenceService _persister;
 
public MyClass(ISomePersistenceService someService)
{
    _persister = someService;
}

[Fact]
public void TestConditionA()
{
    var testResult = GetInitialResult();
}

private InitialResultStructure GetInitialResult()
{   
    var tmp = _persister.Get<InitialResultStructure>("somekey");
    if (tmp != null) then return tmp;

    //Arrange, act, assert
    tmp= new InitialResultStructure {SomeProperty = false, AnotherProperty = "2" };

    _persister.Save("somekey", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

[Fact]
public void TestButGoDeeper()
{
    var testResult = GetInitialResult();
    var goDeeperResult = GetDeeperResult(testResult);
}

private DeeperResult GetDeeperResult(InitialResultStructure input)
{
    var tmp = _persister.Get<DeeperResult>("secondkey");
    if (tmp!=null) return tmp;
    //arrange, act, assert using what you have in input
    tmp = new DeeperResult { YetAnother = false, Previous = input };
    _persister.Save("secondkey", tmp);
    return tmp;
}

You can repeat this ad infinitum.

This will not share the data between the tests but init/fetch it every time resulting in no time saved which is the main goal specified by the OP.

It would be possible to expand on what I've done but persist the results from least detailed to most detailed, and re-use them as appropriate.  It would absolutely require configuring the test runner to execute items in a specific order.  There would be some service needed to handle persistence in a consistent fashion, but it would work.

Yes, that will work, then we need to ensure the tests run in series between multiple classes.

@TomSawyer this code will result in GetInitialResult being executed 2 times, e.g. no actual data is shared between tests, and no time actually saved.

@GuruStron You completely missed my comment about temporarily persisting the data after the first retrieval.
